# Can't change span content inside a td HTML using js/php

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `php` snippet on `Wordpress` that contains a loop through my `SQL` that will create a table for user.

On that `PHP` code, i have a specific var that needs to get a X value from web, i was using `PHP` to do all of it, but since it's not `async`, it causes page load to be `10s~`

I tried use `jQuery/JS`, unfortunately, i couldn't change value inside `<td>`

```
$charstatus = "
<script>
$.get('isOnline.php?name=".$jsName."', function(data) {
    var element = document.querySelector('".$vps.$slot."')
    element.innerHTML = data
});
</script>";
```

Why won't it work?

Comment: To create span class, i'm using:
`echo '<td><center><span class="' .$vps.$slot. '">' . $charstatus . '</span></center></td>';`

Comment: `"Why won't it work?"` - it's hard to say without more information. What debugging have you done already? Have you verified your selector is correct/the element exists/valid HTML is returned in `data`/etc.?

Comment: Yes, if I change function to document.write(data), for example, it'll override my current page with <img> corretly, however it's not what I want.